R grep for multiple string matches in a dataframe (quickly)
I have a data frame of currently about 42000 rows, which draws on data from several thousand pdf files.  One of the columns in the data frame lists the filepath for the pdf that that data comes from.  Some data points are duplicated due to earlier iterations of the data having crept into my data frame.  I have a function that finds the latest iteration for cases when there are multiple iterations, and generates a list of file paths for the pdf file containing the latest iteration of each entry.  I need to filter my original data to include only these latest filepaths.  At the moment, I'm doing that with:
data<-data[grep(paste0(latest_version, collapse="|"), data$path),]

where data is my original data frame and latest_version is the list of correct file paths.  This works, but is very slow.  As I need to update my data frequently, I need a way to do this that works quickly (seconds rather than minutes).  I tried using fixed=T in my grep function call, but for some reason that didn't return any results.  Any thoughts on a more efficient way to approach this?
Edit:
The problem can be simulated by generating dummy data as follows:
test_df<-data.frame(a=c(1:50000), b=c(1:50000), path = do.call(paste0, Map(stri_rand_strings, n=50000, length=c(100, 50, 7),
                                                                        pattern = c('[A-Z]', '[0-9]', '[A-Z]'))))
    test_latest_ver<-test_df$path[sample(50000, 2000)]
    
    final_data<-test_df[grep(paste0(test_latest_ver, collapse="|"), test_df$path),]

Further edit:
10 rows of actual data, randomly selected from the ~42000 rows.
> openlab_data[sample(nrow(openlab_data), 10),] %>% dput()
structure(list(peak = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), rt = c(9.991, 27.143, 8.272, 18.256, 41.274, 21.312, 8.271, 
63.208, 12.088, 9.278), type = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), width = c(0.13, 
NA, 0.233, 0.078, NA, NA, 0.223, NA, NA, 0.076), area = c(180.26731, 
8.416, 124.9817, 369.5725, 3.99009, 12.60704, 40.80956, 12.55449, 
253.7054, 2.97745), area_percent = c(4.2104, 0.2788, 1.7295, 
5.8841, 0.4817, 0.2455, 0.5036, 0.2795, 58.5389, NA), compound = c("a-terpinene", 
"Margaric", "a-pinene", "b-selinene", "cedrol", "trans-b-ocimene", 
"a-pinene", "trans isocitral", "para cymene", "a-pinene"), total.peak.area = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), arl.no = c("ARL2308104", 
"ARL2401611", "20240430 0858203_02", "ARL2402869", "ARL2402614", 
"ARL2402578", "ARL2402217", "ARL2303999", "p-cymene", "viridiflorol"
), sample.name = c("826", "Australia Sandalwood Oil Drum 1 UIN 39975", 
"A24-00-0005-", "Hop Oil 24R00685", "E678B Scented Fragrance ND7973", 
"Banksia Neroline and Lavender BN-", "Rose Otto 11722312", "E staigeriana 2103161", 
"SREF para cymene", "viridiflorol"), acq.time = c("2023-11-24 14:17:33", 
"2024-03-14 22:12:34", "2024-04-30 09:42:05", "2024-05-01 19:49:24", 
"2024-04-23 17:42:56", "2024-04-27 11:08:02", "2024-04-09 22:44:02", 
"2023-07-12 05:27:23", "2023-08-03 23:12:26", "2024-01-03 12:38:59"
), acq.meth = c("EO Base - FID.amx", "FAMES.amx", "EO Base - FID - 6850.amx", 
"EO Base - FID - 6850.amx", "IsoEXT - MS.amx", "IsoEXT - MS.amx", 
"EO Base - FID - 6850.amx", "IsoEXT (long) - MS.amx", "EO Base - MS.amx", 
"QTASingleMultiAnalyte-FID.amx"), proc.meth = c("*GCFID_TTO_with_tridecane.pmx", 
"FAMES_Sandalwood_seed_oil.p", "GCFID_Lemon_EOBASE_LIMS.pmx", 
"GCFID_Hop_EOBASE.pmx", "*GCMS_Scented_Fragrance_ISO_EXT.pmx", 
"*GCMS_Banksia_Nerolina_Lavender_ISO_EXT.pmx", "*GCFID_Rose_EOBASE.pmx", 
"*GCMS_ISO-EXT-long_Euc_staigeriana.pmx", "*GCMS_REF-TTO_EO_BASEMETHOD.pmx", 
"*GCFID_Euc_cloeziana_BPX5_SingleMultiAnalyte.pmx"), gc = c("GC-10", 
"GC-10", "GC-03", "GC-03", "GCMS-04", "GCMS-04", "GC-03", "GCMS-04", 
"GCMS-04", "GC-06"), path = c("W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-10/DB-35/GC-10-231124.rslt/ARL2308104_1_0001.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/FAMES/240314.rslt/Australia Sandalwood Oil Drum 1 UIN 39975/ARL2401611_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-03/DB-35/QCB2404-00204-20240430 085820.rslt/20240430 0858203_02_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-03/DB-35/GC-03-240501.rslt/ARL2402869_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GCMS-04/BPX-5/GCMS-04-240423.rslt/ARL2402614_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GCMS-04/BPX-5/GCMS-04-240426.rslt/ARL2402578_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-03/DB-35/GC-03-240409.rslt/ARL2402217_1_0001.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GCMS-04/BPX-5/230711_EOPAA.rslt/ARL2303999_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GCMS-04/DB-35/230803.rslt/p-cymene_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-06/BPX-5/240103.rslt/viridiflorol_1_0001.pdf"
)), row.names = c(46002L, 1934L, 7806L, 6119L, 14343L, 14627L, 
4038L, 50288L, 53578L, 9055L), class = "data.frame")

In the full data frame, the path to any given pdf file would typically appear in 10 - 20 rows.  Some of those pdf files need to be excluded from this data frame.  Identifying which ones need to be retained is handled separately, and produces the list I've called latest_version.
For the purpose of the example data, you could use:
latest_version<-list("W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GCMS-04/DB-35/230803.rslt/p-cymene_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-06/BPX-5/240103.rslt/viridiflorol_1_0001.pdf")

In reality, 99% of the file paths would be retained.  And the efficiency of the solution is really a factor of the size of the list and data frame (and it seems, the number of characters in the strings).
I'm wondering if fixed=T doesn't work in my original [grep()] approach because of the nature of the strings in question, and whether this is also causing problems with the right_join approach.

How about duplicated(..., fromLast = TRUE)

Please share a small reproducible example including sample input and desired output. There is probably a faster way, but it's very hard to tell with just a text description.

Using data<-data[grep(paste0(latest_version, collapse="|"), data$path, perl = TRUE),] might speed the search up; it's hard to say without a minimal reproducible example

@Dave2e no, duplicated won't work, the rows aren't identical, the ones that need removing are just superceded.

@jaren_mamrot adding perl=T throws an error that the search term is an invalid regular expression, and a warning message that the regular expression is too large.

@Gregor Thomas I can't really share my actual data, but I'll see if I can come up with some fake data that reproduces the problem.  Really its a general question about how to filter a dataframe for multiple strings in a given column in an efficient manner.

Yes, and efficiency is best gauged by a benchmark, and benchmarks require test data. Test data that accurately reflects the problem, as evidenced by your comments on the one answer so far.

@Gregor Thomas I added a few rows of real data in case the structure of the data frame or the format of the strings in the path column are impacting on possible solutions, but its not going to be very useful for benchmarking because the size of the list and dataframe and the number of characters in the strings in the path column seem to be the biggest factors in slowing down the [grep()] approach.

Using the join function from the dplyr package should provide improvement.
I still don't quite understand the problem, that need to update the paths but you are using the paths as the matching variable.
#use code from question here to define test_df and test_latest_ver

library(dplyr)
 
latest_ver<-list("W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GCMS-04/DB-35/230803.rslt/p-cymene_1.pdf", 
                  "W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-06/BPX-5/240103.rslt/viridiflorol_1_0001.pdf",
                  "New Link")

#create a new df with the new paths
latest_df <- data.frame(latest=unlist(latest_ver))


#now use the left join function to match the paths
answer <- left_join(test_df, latest_df, by=join_by(path==latest), keep=TRUE)

#change the name of the added column
#names(answer)[names(answer)=="latest"] <- "path"

Now the answer data frame will have a new column with the new matching link.  I leave it to the reader to either filter out the rows with the NAs (filter(answer, !is.na(latest)) or set "keep=FALSE") or copy the old links over.
If there are new links in latest_ver then use full_join() to create new rows with the added links.
On my machine this should be ~700x improvement in speed.

That's definitely faster with the dummy data, but in the actual data multiple rows can legitimately have the same value in the path column.  Will this still work with the join approach?

When I apply this approach to my actual data, the result is a data.frame with 2936 rows, as compared to the approach using grep, which gives me a data.frame of 41504 rows.

Can you provide a better example? 10 rows of data and what the expected output is.  I’m not clear on what you have or teying to do. You could left join your data and keep the original data frame

I updated my question with 10 rows of real data.  The idea is to retain only the rows where the path column in the data frame matches any of the strings in the latest_version list.

From your sample data, it appear you are looking for exact matches of whole strings, not matches of substrings. For this, regex is not necessary. You can simply use %in%.
Using your sample data:
openlab_sample = structure(list(peak = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), rt = c(9.991, 27.143, 8.272, 18.256, 41.274, 21.312, 8.271, 
63.208, 12.088, 9.278), type = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), width = c(0.13, 
NA, 0.233, 0.078, NA, NA, 0.223, NA, NA, 0.076), area = c(180.26731, 
8.416, 124.9817, 369.5725, 3.99009, 12.60704, 40.80956, 12.55449, 
253.7054, 2.97745), area_percent = c(4.2104, 0.2788, 1.7295, 
5.8841, 0.4817, 0.2455, 0.5036, 0.2795, 58.5389, NA), compound = c("a-terpinene", 
"Margaric", "a-pinene", "b-selinene", "cedrol", "trans-b-ocimene", 
"a-pinene", "trans isocitral", "para cymene", "a-pinene"), total.peak.area = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), arl.no = c("ARL2308104", 
"ARL2401611", "20240430 0858203_02", "ARL2402869", "ARL2402614", 
"ARL2402578", "ARL2402217", "ARL2303999", "p-cymene", "viridiflorol"
), sample.name = c("826", "Australia Sandalwood Oil Drum 1 UIN 39975", 
"A24-00-0005-", "Hop Oil 24R00685", "E678B Scented Fragrance ND7973", 
"Banksia Neroline and Lavender BN-", "Rose Otto 11722312", "E staigeriana 2103161", 
"SREF para cymene", "viridiflorol"), acq.time = c("2023-11-24 14:17:33", 
"2024-03-14 22:12:34", "2024-04-30 09:42:05", "2024-05-01 19:49:24", 
"2024-04-23 17:42:56", "2024-04-27 11:08:02", "2024-04-09 22:44:02", 
"2023-07-12 05:27:23", "2023-08-03 23:12:26", "2024-01-03 12:38:59"
), acq.meth = c("EO Base - FID.amx", "FAMES.amx", "EO Base - FID - 6850.amx", 
"EO Base - FID - 6850.amx", "IsoEXT - MS.amx", "IsoEXT - MS.amx", 
"EO Base - FID - 6850.amx", "IsoEXT (long) - MS.amx", "EO Base - MS.amx", 
"QTASingleMultiAnalyte-FID.amx"), proc.meth = c("*GCFID_TTO_with_tridecane.pmx", 
"FAMES_Sandalwood_seed_oil.p", "GCFID_Lemon_EOBASE_LIMS.pmx", 
"GCFID_Hop_EOBASE.pmx", "*GCMS_Scented_Fragrance_ISO_EXT.pmx", 
"*GCMS_Banksia_Nerolina_Lavender_ISO_EXT.pmx", "*GCFID_Rose_EOBASE.pmx", 
"*GCMS_ISO-EXT-long_Euc_staigeriana.pmx", "*GCMS_REF-TTO_EO_BASEMETHOD.pmx", 
"*GCFID_Euc_cloeziana_BPX5_SingleMultiAnalyte.pmx"), gc = c("GC-10", 
"GC-10", "GC-03", "GC-03", "GCMS-04", "GCMS-04", "GC-03", "GCMS-04", 
"GCMS-04", "GC-06"), path = c("W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-10/DB-35/GC-10-231124.rslt/ARL2308104_1_0001.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/FAMES/240314.rslt/Australia Sandalwood Oil Drum 1 UIN 39975/ARL2401611_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-03/DB-35/QCB2404-00204-20240430 085820.rslt/20240430 0858203_02_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-03/DB-35/GC-03-240501.rslt/ARL2402869_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GCMS-04/BPX-5/GCMS-04-240423.rslt/ARL2402614_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GCMS-04/BPX-5/GCMS-04-240426.rslt/ARL2402578_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-03/DB-35/GC-03-240409.rslt/ARL2402217_1_0001.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GCMS-04/BPX-5/230711_EOPAA.rslt/ARL2303999_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GCMS-04/DB-35/230803.rslt/p-cymene_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-06/BPX-5/240103.rslt/viridiflorol_1_0001.pdf"
)), row.names = c(46002L, 1934L, 7806L, 6119L, 14343L, 14627L, 
4038L, 50288L, 53578L, 9055L), class = "data.frame")

latest_version<-list("W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GCMS-04/DB-35/230803.rslt/p-cymene_1.pdf", 
"W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-06/BPX-5/240103.rslt/viridiflorol_1_0001.pdf")

First we will convert latest_version to a vector as there is no reason to use a list here. Then we will do a standard subset using %in%, keeping only rows where openlab_sample$path is %in% the latest_version vector. You haven't provided the desired output, so I can only assume the result is correct--it matches the result from your grep code. I'd note that you include a bunch of columns in the sample data that seem irrelevant to the problem, which makes the problem less clear.
latest_version <- unlist(latest_version)
openlab_sample[openlab_sample$path %in% latest_version, ]
#       peak     rt type width      area area_percent    compound total.peak.area       arl.no
# 53578   NA 12.088 <NA>    NA 253.70540      58.5389 para cymene              NA     p-cymene
# 9055    NA  9.278 <NA> 0.076   2.97745           NA    a-pinene              NA viridiflorol
#            sample.name            acq.time                      acq.meth
# 53578 SREF para cymene 2023-08-03 23:12:26              EO Base - MS.amx
# 9055      viridiflorol 2024-01-03 12:38:59 QTASingleMultiAnalyte-FID.amx
#                                              proc.meth      gc
# 53578                  *GCMS_REF-TTO_EO_BASEMETHOD.pmx GCMS-04
# 9055  *GCFID_Euc_cloeziana_BPX5_SingleMultiAnalyte.pmx   GC-06
#                                                                                                          path
# 53578        W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GCMS-04/DB-35/230803.rslt/p-cymene_1.pdf
# 9055  W:/ARL/Analytical/USER/Essential Oils/..LABDATA/OpenLab/GC-06/BPX-5/240103.rslt/viridiflorol_1_0001.pdf

Benchmarking, on this tiny data, %in% is about twice as fast as your approach. However, if we resample your data to have 100k rows, then %in% is about 40x faster. I suspect also that as the length of latest_version increases, the regex will be much slower. If you want even more speed, the data.table package provides a function %chin% which is version of %in%` optimized for character vectors.
openlab_big = openlab_sample[sample(1:nrow(openlab_sample), size = 1e5, replace = TRUE), ]

bench::mark(
  in_subset = openlab_big[openlab_big$path %in% latest_version, ],
  grep = openlab_big[grep(paste0(latest_version, collapse="|"), openlab_big$path), ]
)
# # A tibble: 2 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>
# 1 in_subset    16.5ms     27ms     32.0     11.4MB    14.0     16     7      500ms <df>  
# 2 grep          620ms    620ms      1.61       3MB     1.61     1     1      620ms <df>  

On the test_df you provide with larger strings, %in% and %chin% work in 0.004 and 0.003 seconds, respectively, on my laptop. The grep approach I terminated after waiting for several minutes.

Some notes on regex and fixed
You don't seem to have a good understanding of what regex is for or what a "fixed" regex search is.

regex is good for looking for patterns within strings. For example, you could test strings to see if they contain "a", or of they contain any numbers, or if they contain 5 numbers followed by a dash followed by three letters.
if your pattern has no variability, e.g., you are always looking for the exactly "abcd", then you can set fixed = TRUE to greatly improve the efficiency of the regex. This ignores all special characters in regex, like . for matching any character, | for OR, quantifiers, wildcards, etc. The way you are using grep in the question, you are using the | special character to mean OR, so you cannot use fixed = TRUE.
If your pattern includes special regex characters, like . that matches any single character, * which is a quantifier, $ the is the end of the string, | which means OR, but you want them to be treated literally (have . match only a ., ignoring its special meaning), then you need to escape the special characters with two backslashes.

my guess is that Dave2e's answer using the join actually works well, and it is your grep approach that is wrong, returning too many results because the unescaped special characters in your regex are matching rows you don't intend.


if you are looking for entire string equality (which it seems you are), then you don't need regex at all. In R, we would use == or %in% as appropriate to test equality of whole strings.


Thanks for the clarity on why fixed=TRUE wasn't working for me.  I am trying to match exact strings, but I didn't think about how the "|" was interpreted here.  Unfortunately the %in% approach isn't working.  Contrary to your guess, the grep approach does actually work correctly.  I realise that the grep function will interpret the fullstops in the path strings as wildcards, but that isn't going to lead to inclusion of additional data in this instance, although it might be part of the reason it is so slow.  The %in% approach, similarly to the right_join approach, is producing an output that is

... far too short.  In my data frame, there are at present 2312 unique path strings.  The latest_version vector has 2267 unique file paths.  So the requirement is only to remove 45 filepaths from the 2312 paths.  The final data frame should have not many rows less than the original one (maybe a few hundred).  This is what happens with the grep approach.  The %in% approach only returns 718 rows.  The right_join approach returns 2942 rows.  I have no idea why this is the case, because obviously both approaches work for the sample data I gave you, which is actual data from my data frame.

My full data frame, prior to removing the superseded data, has 41592 rows.  After removing the superseded data with the grep approach, I have 40846 rows.

If you can provide a reproducible example that demonstrates where these approaches fail, that would help a lot. Looking at the join answer more closely, I think it misunderstands your problem - I would use inner_join rather than left_join, and then it should match the %in% approach exactly. But I cannot really imagine what rows are being kept correctly by your grep approach but dropped by %in%. If you could make a small reproducible example that includes some of those rows, then maybe we could get somewhere. But without being able to see the issue, there's little more I can do.

You might be able to get a performance improvement if you called stringi::stri_detect_fixed() on each pattern individually and then using | on the resulting boolean vectors (rather than using | within the regex). The fixed option is much more memory efficient. To do it most efficiently you'd want to loop over the patterns and keep track of which rows have hits already and skip them in subsequent iterations.

So in the end I changed tactic and instead of passing a list of all the file paths I wanted to keep, I generated the much shorter list of all the ones I wanted to get rid of.  Doing that, grepping with invert=T gave the same result as using ! %in%.  Both approaches were much quicker than my original approach, but the %in% method is definitely better.
